# how to generate infinite counter

Tags: php, count, counter

Do you suggest how to develop a counter that automatically produces this sequence for me until infinity?

```
> if($id_bilo_up<25000){
    >             $directoryUP = 'da0';
    >         }else if ($id_bilo_up>=25000 && $id_bilo_up<50000){
    >             $directoryUP = 'da25000';
    >         }else if ($id_bilo_up>=50000 && $id_bilo_up<75000){
    >             $directoryUP = 'da50000';
    >         }else if ($id_bilo_up>=75000 && $id_bilo_up<100000){
    >             $directoryUP = 'da75000';
    >         }else if ($id_bilo_up>=100000 && $id_bilo_up<125000){
    >             $directoryUP = 'da100000';
    >         }else if ($id_bilo_up>=125000 && $id_bilo_up<150000){
    >             $directoryUP = 'da125000';
    >         }else if ($id_bilo_up>=150000 && $id_bilo_up<175000){
    >             $directoryUP = 'da150000';
    >         }else if ($id_bilo_up>=175000 && $id_bilo_up<200000){
    >             $directoryUP = 'da175000';
    >         }else if ($id_bilo_up>=200000 && $id_bilo_up<225000){
    >             $directoryUP = 'da200000';
    >         }
```

Comment: Infinity is very - very big. No computer, no matter how fast, and advanced, will be able to do this for you. I guess you don't really mean "infinity"?

Comment: why not just do  `$directoryUP = 'da'.$id_bilo_up;`? or  `$directoryUP = 'da'.(ceil($id_bilo_up / 25000) * 25000);` if you want rounding? Is there any reason you need the value to be in sets of 25k?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That looks more like a beginning of an answer than a comment. Why not make it into an answer?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have to send the object back to the correct directory. Example my object number 323,000 must enter the 'da300 directory
.000 'this is because my server binds me to have directories up to a maximum of 25k

Comment: So actually it's not infinity then, there's a defined maximum? Please always be clear and precise when writing your requirements, don't generalise or exaggerate. As you've seen, that just lead to queries about what you're really trying to do or questioning the practicality of it, and also potentially leads to answers which aren't useful.

Comment: @ADyson Yes and no! Every day the value of my objects increases, it never has an end.
it is possible that in a month it will exceed a million and so on

Comment: A million is tiny, insignificant, compared to infinity. But I get your point. You have a lot of "objects", probably files, and you want to store them without going over the 25k limit per directory.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware exact

Comment: I would go with the suggestion of @LawrenceCherone . Perhaps something like: `$directoryUP = 'da' . (ceil($id_bilo_up / 5000) * 5000);` because you should never sail too close to limits. They are limits for a reason.

Comment: I would also advice against storing a million of individual files per month. You can do it, but it after a few years it will really become unmanageable. Can't you use a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments, I better understood what you need:

```
$base=intdiv($id_bilo_up, 25000);
$directoryUP = 'da' . ($base*25) .'000';
```

This will do what you need, but keep in mind that this will break once $base*25>PHP_INT_MAX

Comment: Just to be clear, `PHP_INT_MAX`  is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (on a 64-bit system) which is as good as infinite when you have 1 million items a month.

Comment: yes, before he will reach the limit by the provider on the main directory. Probably at $id_bilo_up=625000000 which is 25000x25000